# How to make 2 different tables having different number of rows to be of same height

Tags: html, css

I have 2 different tables. Both the tables varies in the number of rows it have. I need both the tables to be displayed of the same height..

I want the 2nd table rows to be adjusted in such a way that it too expands to the same height as 1st table.

Comment: Sample that I have tried is given here:   http://jsfiddle.net/WTNeB/277/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$("#div2").height($("#div1").height());
```

for load the correct height on the second div

and on the second table add

```
style="height: 100%"
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BL9t2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap classes

`row class` and `col class`.

You can go check **[this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WTNeB/277/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to see witch one of those tables have a bigger height and after that you should make the other one like it.

Considering that both of your tables have a class called for example `mytable`, the script you need to load after the document is ready is this:

```
var heights = $(".mytable").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get(),
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

$(".mytable").height(maxHeight);
```